# Find point at which secant crosses circumference of circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I don't know the proper terminology, or even how to draw the right diagram, but I'm looking to work out `a` for any given `y`.

[image]

- `a` = the thick, horizontal line, distance from `y` to circle's
  edge
- `x` = can be considered the x axis
- `y` = can be considered the y
  axis
- pink line is the secant (I love Wikipedia)

So `a` must get shorter, the further down `y` it is drawn. The second, lower thick horizontal line `a` shows this.

I know `a` (I know the radius of the circle) and I know the length of the second, lower line `a` (because I know the distance along `x` from the center to the pink line).

I want to find out `V`, that is, a vector describing where the pink line bisects the circle. My idea is that (I'm a programmer not a mathematician) as line `a` moves 'south' along `y`, it must shorten according to some ratio or function of the radius of the circle.

So `y` and `a` are related by some function of the radius. Probably.

If someone knows that function, then I can work out `y` for any given `a`. So knowing `x`, I can then work out `y` in terms of `x` and arrive at `V`.

If someone has a better way to work out `V`, then let me know. In real life, the pink line is at an angle, but I will rotate the entire coordinate space, work out `V` and then rotate it back :)

Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You have two $a$'s that do not look to be the same.  Please give one (probably the lower one) a different name.

Comment: @RossMillikan Is there anything else wrong? I'd rather correct the diagram once than 5 times and keep uploading a pic and checking the comments, heuristically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the upper $a$ be $r$, the radius of the circle.  The length of the diagonal blue line is then also $r$.  The coordinates of $V$ are $(V_x,V_y)$ By the Pythagorean theorem we have $V_x^2+V_y^2=r^2$ and $V_x=a$, so $V=(a,\sqrt{r^2-a^2})$

Comment: I'll change my diagram so upper `a` is `r`.

Comment: I changed it back. With an updated diagram, my entire question needs revising! Let's leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I dign't get it, so sorry!

But if you know $y$ and the radius, say $r$, then from Pythagorean theorem follows that $a=\sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$ and the coordinate of the vector $V$ in the coordinate system ${X,Y}$ in the picture would be $V=(a,y)$ (I'm assuming the orientation of the $Y$-axis is downward (as suggests the arrow).

Sorry if I misunderstood something!

Comment: Sorry i didn't mean to duplicate an answer, when i started editing there was no answers at all, and my browser didn't refresh!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I wasn't. I don't know `y` but I do know both `a`s.